# Compare python time with MySQL time format

Tags: python, mysql, date

I have this if statement in python:

```
if acceso < dateString < spento:
  [SOME CODE]
else:
  [OTHER CODE]
```

where:

```
dateString = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

and acceso and spento are the results of a MySQL query:

```
orario = ("SELECT * FROM orari WHERE attivo = 1")
        cur.execute(orario)
        row = cur.fetchone()
        acceso = datetime.strftime(row[1], '%H:%M:%S')
        spento = datetime.strftime(row[2], '%H:%M:%S')
```

if I manually set acceso and spento to a value like this 06:00:00 and 22:00:00 the script works well. I've tried some methods to convert row[1] and row[2] to a datetime object and this give me this error:

> TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'datetime.timedelta'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the easiest way: change the MySQL field type from time to text. Not the best, but in my case I don't need a more accurate method.